# python multiple time-stamps into pandas.tslib.Timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, strptime

I have a DF containing time-stamps, e.g.,

```
0    2014-12-18 10:47:37
1    2014-12-18 10:47:37
2    2014-12-18 10:47:37
3    2015-01-30 04:50:49
4    2015-03-01 11:16:41
```

I want to divide this into timeslots of, say, 30 minutes each. The way I see to do it is by converting the time-stamp into 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp' than epoch and dividing these into bins. 
BUT. The first step of converting into datetime.datetime.strptime works only on strings and not dataframes or lists. So the only way i found to convert the entire DF into pandas.tslib.Timestamp is by going row after row:

```
for k in range(len(tbl)):
        tbl.iloc[k] = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(tbl[k]),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

This is slow and obviously there is a way to do it as a single shot.
Please advise.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def time_norm(tmp,delta_T):
    epoch_ms = tmp.astype(np.int64)//1000000L
    tbl  = epoch_ms//delta_T
    tbl = tbl - tbl.min()
    return tbl

delta_T = 1000 #1 sec
tmp = pd.to_datetime(tbl)
tbl = time_norm(tmp,delta_T)
```

At some point pd.to_datetime didn't work at some point so I avoided using it. Turns out it's still the solution...